# How can JAXB be used to map attributes on an element to fields of an intrinsic property of a POJO?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Let's pretend I have the following XML:

```
<company name="Sun" country="Atlantis" state="Syracuse" city="Troy">
</company>
```

With JAXB, and without using third-party extensions such as EclipseLink's `@XmlPath`, is there a way to unmarshall it into the following POJO structure:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Company {

    private String name;

    private Address address;

    // getters and setters

}

public class Address {

    private String country;

    private String state;

    private String city;

    // getters and setters

}

company.getAddress().getCountry(); // Atlantis
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular scenario can be handled using an `XmlAdapter`:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class CompanyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<CompantType, Company> {

    @Override
    public CompanyType marshal(Company in) throws Exception {
        CompanyType out = new CompanyType();

        out.setName(in.getName());
        out.setCountry(in.getAddress().getCountry());
        // ...

        return out;
    }

    @Override
    public Company unmarshall(CompanyType in) throws Exception {
        Company out = new Company();

        out.setName(in.getName());

        Address add = new Address();
        add.setCountry(in.getCountry());

        out.setAddress(add);

        // ...

        return out;
    }
}
```